# Class.forName is not loading data from the specified directory

Tags: java

I have a Java file named `Customer.java`, in a folder `d:/sample directory`. But when I use `Class.forName("d:/sample/Customer")` it throws an exception as file not found. I tried with `Class.forName("d:/sample/Customer.java")` also but get the same exception. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: class to be loaded

```
package com.test;
class Example{
    //empty class
}
```

2: save the file to : d:/example/com/test/Example.java

2: compile the class:

```
javac  d:/example/com/test/Example.java
```

...

3: write test class:

```
package com.test;
class MainClass{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
        System.out.println(Class.forName("com.test.Example"));
    }
}
```

4: compile the class:

```
javac  d:/example/com/test/MainClass.java
```

...

5: run the program:

```
java -cp D:/example/ com.test.MainClass
```

result:

```
class com.test.Example
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Class.forName()` method takes the fully qualified name (FQN) of a class, not a file. So for example you would use it as

```
Class.forName("Customer");
```

Assuming your Customer class is in the default package. It's always a good idea to consult the JavaDocs when you are having issues using a SDK method. For future reference, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Class.html) is the documentation for the method you are trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the [JavaDoc's on Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) for proper use of the forName method. The method requires "the fully qualified name of the desired class." An example is as follows:

```
Class t = Class.forName("java.lang.Thread")
```

Your Customer.java class must be on the ClassPath if you wish to load it in that method. Then you must load it by the fully qualified path, aka the package then the class name.

Answer (score 1):

1. Compile your .java file to .class file
2. Add the .class file into class paths(i.e. via `java -cp d:/sample/;  MainClass`)
3. Then, code like this: `Class.forName("Customer");`

Comment: Can you give me some example programs about it